# Java getSubimage() outside of raster

Tags: java, bufferedimage, raster

I'm trying to take an image and store it in an array of 16x16 subimages. The image I am using is 512x512 pixels. However, while iterating through the loop, getSubimage() is stopped by a Raster exception.

Here is the code:

```
public class TileList extends JPanel {

  private static final int width = 16;          //width of a tile
  private static final int height = width;
  private int col = 1;
  private int row = 1;

  private BufferedImage image;
  File tilesetImage = new File("image.png");
  BufferedImage tileset[];

  public void loadAndSplitImage (File loadImage) {
    try{
        image = ImageIO.read(loadImage);
    }catch(Exception error) {
        System.out.println("Error: cannot read tileset image.");
    }// end try/catch
    col = image.getWidth()/width;
    row = image.getHeight()/height;
    tileset = new BufferedImage[col*row];
  }// end loadAndSplitImage

  public TileList() {
    loadAndSplitImage(tilesetImage);
    setLayout(new GridLayout(row,col,1,1));
    setBackground(Color.black);

    int x=0;
    int y=0;
    int q=0;                                    //keeps track of tile #
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {

        for (int j = 0; j < col; j++) {
            JPanel panel = new JPanel();
            tileset[q] = new BufferedImage(width, height, image.getType());
            tileset[q] = image.getSubimage(x,y,x + width,y + height);
            panel.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(tileset[q])));
            add(panel);
            x += width;
            q++;
        }// end for loop
        y += height;
        x = 0;
    }// end for loop
  }// end constructor
}// end class
```

This is the error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.awt.image.RasterFormatException: (x
+ width) is outside of Raster
    at sun.awt.image.ByteInterleavedRaster.createWritableChild(ByteInterleav
edRaster.java:1245)
    at java.awt.image.BufferedImage.getSubimage(BufferedImage.java:1173)
    at TileList.<init>(TileList.java:59)
    at TileList.createAndShowGui(TileList.java:79)
    at TileList$1.run(TileList.java:88)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:251)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:721)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:682)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:680)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDo
main.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:691)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThre
ad.java:244)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.
java:163)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThre
ad.java:151)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:147)

    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:139)

    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:97)
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You're passing the wrong parameters to `getSubimage`.  The docs say...

> Parameters:
> x - the X coordinate of the upper-left corner of the specified rectangular region
> y - the Y coordinate of the upper-left corner of the specified rectangular region
> w - the width of the specified rectangular region
> h - the height of the specified rectangular region

You're passing in `x, y, x + width, y + width`, which would mean if `x` = 256, `width` actually equals `256 + 16 = 272`.

So your new image would be ... `x + width = 256 + 272 = 528`, which is wider then your image area.

You should be passing `x, y, width, heigh`

```
tileset[q] = image.getSubimage(x, y, width, height);
```

Answer (score 0):

From the javadoc

```
* @param x the X coordinate of the upper-left corner of the
*          specified rectangular region
* @param y the Y coordinate of the upper-left corner of the
*          specified rectangular region
* @param w the width of the specified rectangular region
* @param h the height of the specified rectangular region
```

this means the following line is wrong

```
image.getSubimage(x,y,x + width,y + height);
```

it should be something like

```
image.getSubimage(x, y, width, height);
```

For a full working example take a look at this [paste](http://www.nomorepasting.com/getpaste.php?pasteid=39032)